# Python re.split with comma and parenthesis "(" and ")"

Tags: python, regex, split

so I got this code:

```
from dosql import *
import cgi
import simplejson as json
import re

def index(req, userID):
    userID = cgi.escape(userID)

    get = doSql()
    rec = get.execqry("select get_progressrecord('" + userID + "');",False)[0][0]
    result = str(rec)
    stringed = re.split(',', result)

    return json.dumps(stringed)
```

And it returns this:

[image]

But I want to exclude the parenthesis "**(**" "**)**" too. How could I put multiple delimiters in the regex?

Comment: Why is [Nick Barnes' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26158124/182971) not satisfactory?

Comment: `result = str(rec)` why would you do that only to split the string back afterward?

Comment: You can use parens with a `,` instead of splitting on parens separetly. Something like `\(*\)*,\(*\)*` depending on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), you can remove surround characters specified:

```
>>> row = ["(178.00", "65.00", "20.52", "normal", "18", "0.00)"]
>>> [x.strip('(),') for x in row]
['178.00', '65.00', '20.52', 'normal', '18', '0.00']
```

BTW, if `get.execqry(..)` returns a tuple, string manipulation is not necessary.

```
a_tuple = get.execqry(....)
# or (if you want a list)
a_list = list(get.execqry(....))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a | between them:

```
stringed = re.split(',|(|)', result)
```

Comment: Easier would be `[,()]`, no?

Comment: Easier would probably be not casting the query resultset to a string first.

Comment: @Barmar does that really work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
[,()]
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN8oK4/1)**

[image]

The idea is to match the characters you want using a regex class `[`...`]`. So, this will match commas or parentheses.

On the other hand, if you want to capture the following content:

```
(250.00", "612.00", "55.55", "normal", "1811", "0.00)
```

You could use something like this:

```
([\w.]+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN8oK4/2)**

[image]